# Getting ReferenceError: appearance is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, api

I am trying to access an super hero api and for some of the data it keeps saying that the data is undefined.

```
 var html = "";
$.each(data.results,function(i,results){
html += "<li> first appearance: " + results.biography.first-appearance +"</li>";
// it is not showing anything with a "-" in but the rest are working fine 

 })
 $("#Results").html(html);
```

Comment: What’s `appearance` and why are you subtracting it from `first`?

Comment: You cannot use dashes in property names when using dot notation, you need to use bracket notation `biography['first-appearence']`

Comment: Yours worked!  Patrick Evans  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way that object keys with hyphens in them need to be quoted, when you're *accessing* the key you need to use square bracket notation with quotes:

```js
const a = [{ biography: 'a', 'first-appearance': 'b' }];
    
console.log(a[0]['first-appearance'])
```